# Are deaths tracked in Halo: MCC?

Tags: halo-the-master-chief-collection

I recently got back into playing Halo: MCC after they added Halo: Reach to the game. I checked the in-game matchmaking stats, curious to see what my kill death ratio is, and I was surprised not to find any recorded death count. I could have sworn that deaths used to be recorded and visible on the stats screen.

Is there a way to see how many times you've died in online multiplayer in Halo: MCC?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found that while the the death count is not displayed on the main menu's career screen, it is visible from each player's Player Details screen. You can access this by selecting a player's nameplate from the list of players in your session and navigating to Player Details > Career > Multiplayer.

[image]